# How to use string match() with angularJs $scope.search variable

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, match

I try to use string match with **ignore case sensitivity** and my input `$scope.search` variable, but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" autofocus="autofocus">




angular.forEach(groups, function(group, key) {

   console.log(group); // => Object contains

    if (group.label.match(/($scope.search)/i)) {
      result[key] = group;
    }

});
```

Data Object group:

```
Object { label: "Transfiguration", articles: Array[1] }
```

How to use **group.lable.match()** with `$scope.search` correctly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is dynamic so you cannot use `/regexp/` syntax. You need to create a [`Regexp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object instead.

```
angular.forEach(groups, function(group, key) {
    console.log(group); // => Object contains

    if (group.label.match(new RegExp("(" + $scope.search + ")", "i"))) {
      result[key] = group;
    }
});
```

You can probably remove the brackets from the RegExp too.

It is better also to use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) because you aren't interested in the results:

```
if(new RegExp($scope.search, "i").test(group.label)) {
```

Finally, if this is a basic search, putting both parts to lower case and using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) should be more efficient:

```
if (group.label.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use javascript in angularjs modules :)

```
angular.forEach(groups, function(group, key) {

   console.log(group); // => Object contains

    if (group.label.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
      result[key] = group;
    }

});
```

This should solve your problem